# Proving/disproving statements with a given context of natural numbers.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, quantifiers

How do I prove the following statements or their negations in the context where $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers in the closed interval $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$?

Statement 1: $\forall x \exists y\; x < y$ ;
Negation of Statement 1: $\exists x\forall y\; x \geq y$

Statement 2: $\exists y \forall x\; x < y$ ;
Negation of Statement 2: $\forall y \exists x\; x \geq y$

Statement 3: $\forall y \exists x\; x < y$ ;
Negation of Statement 3: $\exists y\forall x\; x \geq y$

Statement 4: $\exists x \forall y\; x < y$ ;
Negation of Statement 4: $\forall x \exists y\; x \geq y$

Proof of the Negation of Statement 1 for real numbers:
The negation of Statement 1 says that “There is some $x$ such that for all $y$, $x$ is greater than or equal to $y$.”
We can choose an x in the interval in which x would be greater than y to satisfy this statement. If we choose that $x = \sqrt{2}$, then $y$ can be any number in the given interval and the statement will always be true since $\sqrt{2}$ is the upper bound of this interval.

I believe that all the negations are true for the set of real numbers, but I am unsure on how to edit my proofs using real numbers to prove or disprove the above statements if they must be rational numbers on this interval.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give us some context to this question? What are your thoughts so far? Which statements do you think are true?

Comment: Thank you! I believe that all the negations above are true as I have proved them for another question where x,y are real numbers I just want to be sure that I'm correct.
I believe that the negation of Statement 1 is equivalent to "There is some x such that for all y, x is greater than or equal to y." To prove that, we can choose an x in the interval in which x would be greater than or equal to y to satisfy this statement. If we choose that x = √2, then y can be any number in the given interval and the statement will always be true since √2 is the upper bound of this interval. Is this correct?

Comment: These are good thoughts, but not quite right (remember $x$ and $y$ are rational). I would edit your question to include these details. Also, it would be good to reword your question so that it is not imperative. People don't like answering questions that seem like an order.

Comment: Right! The question that I had already proved was dealing with real numbers. I'm unsure as to how to go about this question since x and y are rational.

Comment: Edit your question to include these details, and then I will answer it.

Comment: Is my question clearer now?

Comment: Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1 is true. Let $x\in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ be rational. We know that $x\neq \sqrt{2}$. Then there is another rational number in $(x,\sqrt{2})$. Call this number $y$. Then $x<y$.

Statement 2 is false. Its negation is true; just let $x=y$.

Statement 3 is true. Its proof is similar to the proof of 1.

Statement 4 is false. Its proof is similar to the proof of 2.